# Apache PDFBox PDFTextStripper access text parts of the page, how can I?

Tags: java, extract, pdfbox

I am parsing PDF documents with apache's PDFBox version 2.0.x
I have seen many questions about separating the header/footer from the actual content.
My findings are that there is some notion (in my sample PDF) of these sections since the SortByPosition flag has an effect on the order in which the content is written to text.
When I set SortByPosition to false, I get first the header/footer and next the body (and this repeats for every page).
When I set SortByPostion to true, I get the content in the order as it appears on the screen in my PDF Reader.

```
PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
textStripper.setSortByPosition(true);

String content = textStripper.getText(pdf);
System.out.println(content);
```

So internally these pieces of text are available a seperate "textblocks".
My question is: is there a way for me to access those block seperately ?

Below the output of this piece of code with the sort flag to true

> Header PDF MIC
>
> Vandaag meer dan 1 pagina
>   Door mij geschreven
>
> 1
>
> Header PDF MIC
>
> Dan is dit pagina 2
>   Met veel meer teksten en woorden.
>
> 2

And this is the output with the sort flag to false

> Header PDF MIC
>
> 1
>
> Vandaag meer dan 1 pagina
>
> Door mij geschreven
>
> Header PDF MIC
>
> 2
>
> Dan is dit pagina 2
>
> Met veel meer teksten en woorden.

Comment: If you know the coordinates, use PDFTextStripperByArea.

Comment: thanks @TilmanHausherr our PDFs will be provided by different suppliers, so we don't know the layout/coordinates in advance, but we can assume a header / footer / page number as well as PDF/A compliance.

Comment: If you are getting PDFs from different suppliers, why do you think you can make use of the internal structure of one PDF to parse them all? *we can assume a header / footer / page number* but how are they to be recognized by a machine? Think of criteria appropriate for your use case, then we might help you implement them. *PDF/A compliance*  what flavor? PDF/A-1a? 1b? 2a? 2b? 2u? 3a? 3b? 3u?

Comment: I must admit that this (the assumption of internal structure) is "data-drive" @mkl , we accept both A-1a and A-1b PDF types. For now it is enough that WHEN the PDF parser detects structure (which is apparently the case given the order of the parts) we will use it. We are trying to go for an 80-20% situation, get 80% of the headers/footers with 20% of the effort...

Comment: For proper PDF/A-1a headers and footers should be appropriately tagged...

Comment: @mkl I am clearly new at this, how can find these tags using PDF box ?

Comment: PDFBox has a `PDFMarkedContentExtractor` and the tags mentioned are among those used for marked content. Thus, that extractor might be the base to build your solution on. I have not used that class yet, though, so I cannot help with it, in particular without a sample document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @mkl for the hints and tips, here is wat I did:

Piece of Java code that uses the PDFMarkedContentExtractor, this only takes the first page, but we can apply this to all pages.
Below the code you can find the output of the System.out log.

```
ExtraMetaData emd = new ExtraMetaData(); //this my own class to carry the header and footer    

PDFMarkedContentExtractor markedContentExtractor = new PDFMarkedContentExtractor();
                markedContentExtractor.processPage(document.getPage(0));
                List<PDMarkedContent>  markedContents = markedContentExtractor.getMarkedContents();
                for (Iterator iterator = markedContents.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                    PDMarkedContent pdMarkedContent = (PDMarkedContent) iterator.next();
                    System.out.println(pdMarkedContent.getTag()+" --> "+pdMarkedContent.getContents()+ " "+pdMarkedContent.getProperties());
                    COSDictionary pdmcProperties = pdMarkedContent.getProperties();
                    if (pdmcProperties.containsKey("Subtype")) {
                        COSBase cosBase =  pdmcProperties.getDictionaryObject("Subtype");
                        if (((COSName)cosBase).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Footer")) {
                            emd.setFooter(getContentAsString(pdMarkedContent));
                        }
                        if (((COSName)cosBase).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Header")) {
                            emd.setHeader(getContentAsString(pdMarkedContent));
                        }           
                    }
                    if (pdmcProperties.containsKey("Attached")) {
                        COSArray cosArray = (COSArray) pdmcProperties.getDictionaryObject("Attached");
                        for (COSBase cosBase2 : cosArray) {
                            if (((COSName)cosBase2).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Bottom")) {
                                emd.setFooter(getContentAsString(pdMarkedContent));
                            }
                            if (((COSName)cosBase2).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Top")) {
                                emd.setHeader(getContentAsString(pdMarkedContent));
                            }           

                        }
                    }

                }
```

Output

> Artifact --> [-,  , 1,  , -,  ]
>   COSDictionary{COSName{Attached}:COSArray{[COSName{Top}]};COSName{Type}:COSName{Pagination};}
>
> Artifact --> [ ]
>   COSDictionary{COSName{Attached}:COSArray{[COSName{Bottom}]};COSName{Type}:COSName{Pagination};}
>
> P --> [M, J,  , -,  , 2, 0, 1, 6, 2, 1, 7, 2,  , /,  , B,  ]
>   COSDictionary{COSName{MCID}:COSInt{0};}